# How to choose appropriate variance parameters when simulating data for a linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, variance

I am in the process of fitting a linear mixed model to artificial data generated using `simr::makeLmer()`, with the goal of conducting power analysis for a study which has not occurred yet. This requires me to set appropriate parameter values for all fixed and random effects I want to estimate. Let's say I want to fit the following model

$$\begin{aligned}
Y &=(\beta_0 + I_0)\\
&\phantom{=(}+ \beta_1treatment_{1} + \beta_2treatment_2\\
&\phantom{=(}+ \beta_3time\\
&\phantom{=(}+ \beta_4treatment_1:time + \beta_5treatment_2:time\\
&\phantom{=(}+ \epsilon\\
I_0 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \tau^2)\ \\
\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)\
\end{aligned}$$

where
:

- $Y$ is a health outcome on a continuous scale
- $treatment$ is categorical with 3 levels, and $treatment_1$ and $treatment_2$ are Helmert coded variables for contrasts I want to make
- $time$ is a dummy variable coding for time point ($t_0 = 0$ and $t_1 = 1$)
- $I_0$ is the by-subject random intercept

For the sake of example, let's say I have a good idea of what each of the fixed parameters ($\beta_0 ... \beta_5$) should be. The remaining pieces are the random effect parameters $\tau$ and $\sigma$. Let's say I also have access to similar interventional studies which report sample-level statistics on $Y$, e.g. "Health outcomes in our sample had mean $\bar{Y}$ and standard deviation of $10$." From these studies, along with expert opinion, I intuit that $Y$ in my sample should also have mean $\bar{Y}$ and standard deviation of $10$.

My question then is, is there some linear dependency that relates the random parameters $\tau$ and $\sigma$ to the standard  deviation of my sample? If there were, I think I'd be able to get a better sense of what these values should be

For instance, I know that in ANOVA, one can partition the total sum of squares into sums of squares between, within and error. Is there an analagous way to partition sums of squares in random effect models? (taking a shot in the dark here but e.g total sum of squares = sum of squares from fixed effects + sum of squares from random effects)